# Do PHP timeouts stop people on the same network loading pages?

Tags: php, http, networking, timeout

If I have a PHP page that is doing a task that takes a long time, and I try to load another page from the same site at the same time, that page won't load until the first page has timed out. For instance if my timeout was set to 60 seconds, then I wouldn't be able to load any other page until 60 seconds after the page that was taking a long time to load/timeout. As far as I know this is expected behaviour.

What I am trying to figure out is whether an erroneous/long loading PHP script that creates the above situation would also affect other people on the same network. I personally thought it was a browser issues (i.e. if I loaded http://somesite.com/myscript.php in chrome and it start working it's magic in the background, I couldn't then load http://somesite.com/myscript2.php until that had timed out, but I *could* load that page in Firefox). However, I've heard contradictory statements, saying that the timeout would happen to everyone on the same network (IP address?).

My script works on some data imported from sage and takes quite a long time to run - sometiems it can timeout before it finishes (i.e. if the sage import crashes over the weeked), so I run it again and it picks up where it left off. I am worried that other staff in the office will not be able to access the site while this is running.

Comment: Could you make the "I've heard contradictory statements" a bit more clear? Where did you hear it, why did you believe it, can you get a source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have here is actually related to the fact that (I'm guessing) you are using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). This may be a bit of a stretch, but it would account for exactly what you describe.

This is not in fact "expected behaviour" unless your web server is set up to run a single process with a single thread, which I highly doubt. This would create a situation where the web server is only able to handle a single request at any one time, and this would affect everybody on the network. This is exactly why your web server probably won't be set up like this - in fact I suspect you will find it is impossible to configure your server like this, as it would make the server somewhat useless. And before some smart alec chimes in with "what about Node.js?" - that is a special case, as I am sure you are already well aware.

When a PHP script has a session open, it has an exclusive lock on the file in which the session data is stored. This means that any subsequent request will block at the call to `session_start()` while PHP tries to acquire that exclusive lock on the session data file - which it can't, because your previous request still has one. As soon as your previous request finishes, it releases it's lock on the file and the next request is able to complete. Since sessions are per-machine (in fact per-browsing *session*, as the name suggests, which is why it works in a different browser) this will not affect other users of your network, but leaving your site set up so that this is an issue even just for you is bad practice and easily avoidable.

The solution to this is to call [`session_write_close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) as soon as you have finished with the session data in a given script. This causes the script to close the session file and release it's lock. You should try and either finish with the session data before you start the long running process, or not call `session_start()` until after it has completed.

In theory you can call `session_write_close()` and then call `session_start()` again later in the script, but I have found that PHP sometimes exhibits buggy behaviour in this respect (I think this is cookie related, but don't quote me on that). Obviously, pay attention to the fact the setting cookies modifies the headers, so you have to call `session_start()` before you output any data or enable output buffering.

For example, consider this script:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if (!isset($_SESSION['someval'])) {
    $_SESSION['someval'] = 1;
  } else {
    $_SESSION['someval']++;
  }

  echo "someval is {$_SESSION['someval']}";

  sleep(10);
```

With the above script, you will have to wait 10 seconds before you are able to make a second request. However, if you add a call to `session_write_close()` after the `echo` line, you will be able to make another request before the previous request has completed.

Comment: I had the exact same problem as the OP described, but this fixed it completely - thanks for providing such an extensive answer!

Comment: @Jeroen No worries, it's a relatively simple but seemingly little-known limitation of sessions, and people rarely make the leap between the effect and the cause as it's not immediately obvious. One usually calls `session_start()` near the top of the script, which prevents the script from doing anything at at all while the session is locked, so you naturally assume the server hasn't started the script. This issue has appeared here before, but you won't find it in a search because people don't usually mention "sessions" in the question, plus you don't know you should be searching for them.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I did not check but I think that each request to the webserver is handled in a thread of its own. Thereby a different request should not be blocked. Just try :-) Use a different browser and access your page while the big script is running!

Err.. I just see that this worked for you :-) And it should for others, too.