# PHP - Check if page refresh or post data on the same page

Tags: php, post, page-refresh

Is there any way to know if the page was refreshed or data was posted data on the same page?

To be little more specific:

- I have to post data on the same page.
- This affects the where condition of the query.
- If the page was refreshed, then the where condition must be 1.
- Otherwise, where condition contains some id to get specific data from
  the table.

Comment: You cannot know if it was a refresh or the first request, unless you're adding some flag to the page on server side after first request

Comment: I think your problem is when user refresh page it shouldn't save data again.

Comment: Maybe this is a matter of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Aren't you looking for the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), along with your submitted data in `$_POST`. Let's presume for this example you have the following form:

```
<form action="this_page.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="important-info" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then elsewhere in the same page is the PHP code:

```
<?php
// example code
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['previousVisitor']) && isset($_POST['important-info'])) {
  // this is a new visitor who has submitted the form
  $_SESSION['previousVisitor'] = true;
  // where is based on $_POST['important-info']
} else () {
  // where is 1
}

// close the session after you do what you need - this stops large pages causing hang
session_destroy();
```

Please note that they can clear this session variable by deleting their cookies.

Comment: A note about `session_destroy()` is weird

Comment: It caused me headaches a while back (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911429/do-php-timeouts-stop-people-on-the-same-network-loading-pages) - I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Well, I guess the question might be misinterpreted. I have one submit button on the page that that posts data on the same page. I need to know whether the button was clicked or page was refreshed.

Using session previousvisitor, I am getting always 1 (in both refresh and submit button clicked cases)

Comment: Now I understand your problem more I'd suggest that you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get as PeeHaa 埽 suggested - because in this sense you're not really checking for a refresh as the browser will just resubmit the information for you as if the button was pressed. There are other hacks - but I'd try that link first.

Answer (score 1):

on the top of the page just include

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name']!=''){
//your code goes here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check request

```
//Here goes the code
session_start();
$counter = 0;
$counter = (isset($_SESSION['param'])) ? $counter++ : 0;

if($counter == 0)
    echo "data GET or POST";
else
    echo "refreshed";
```

** If you want only POST param, use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

Comment: On refresh exactly the same request is sent